# Find the next four largest 4-combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

Find the next four largest 4-combinations of the set 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 after 1,2,3,5.

Not sure how to do this, need some help~!

Comment: Define "largest"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the next ones, increment the last digit as far as you can go, then go back and increment the next to last, bringing the last up as close as you can.